# Boundedness of sequence in real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, limsup-and-liminf, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f : [0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative continuous function and $\limsup\limits_{t\to\infty}f(t)=M<\infty$. Can we deduce that $f$ is bounded from above?

Here is my attempt so far :

I take any random sequence $(t_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset[0,\infty)$ such that $t_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Then, by definition of limit superior, I fix $\varepsilon=1>0$ so that I can have $N_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n>N_{0},\,f(t_{n})<M+1$. Since $t_{N_{0}}<\infty$, then I can deduce $\max\limits_{t\in[0,t_{N_{0}}]}f(t)<\infty$ by continuity of $f$ and $\forall n>N_{0}, f(t_n)<M+1<\infty$. So, my question is how to show that $\sup\limits_{t\in(t_{N_{0}},\infty)}f(t)<\infty$? I know that I choose any arbitrary sequence in the beginning but I cannot see how it helps here.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Don't take a random sequence but a sequence such that $f(t_n)\to\infty$ and deduce a contradiction. Such a sequence would exist if $f$ was unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each closed interval $[n,n+1]$, $n=0,1,...$, take $x_{n}\in[n,n+1]$ as $f(x_{n})$ being maximal on it, so, $f(x_{n})=\sup_{x\in[n,n+1]}f(x)$. Now it is easy to see that $x_{n}\rightarrow\infty$, and hence $\limsup_{n}f(x_{n})\leq M$. But then $\sup_{x\in{\mathbb{R}}}f(x)=\sup_{n}\sup_{x\in[n,n+1]}f(x)=\sup_{n}f(x_{n})$. If $\sup_{n}f(x_{n})$ is attained by some $f(x_{n_{0}})$, then we are done. If it is not attained, we can extract a subsequence $(f(x_{n_{k}}))$ that converges to $\sup_{n}f(x_{n})$, for then $\sup_{n}f(x_{n})\leq\limsup_{n}f(x_{n})\leq M$.

Comment: Easy? Exactly how do you show $x_n\to\infty$?

Comment: $x_{n}\in[n,n+1]$, so $x_{n}\geq n$.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you'd written something else...

Answer (score 1):

If you're not required to do this using sequences, it seems simpler to me to start with the *definition* $$\limsup_{t\to\infty}f(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\sup_{s>t}f(s).$$If that limit is $M<\infty$ there must exist $t$ such that $\sup_{s>t}f(s)\le M+1$. Now $f$ is bounded on $[0,t]$, being continuous, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am worried whether I can actually use that definition or not without any reference to a text book. If you have a good book which refers to this definition, I will appreciate it so much

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra Well how _was_ $\limsup$ defined? What I wrote seems to me to be pretty standard. (I don't have a relevant text handy, sorry. In any case, I'd think that you're supposed to do the exercises _in_ the context of results and definitions as in the course/book; if so a reference to another book would be cheating. But look  at the book you're using - it really could be that the fact that the $\limsup$ is what I said is either the definition or a theorem...)

Comment: It uses the definition with sequence, so I guess I still have to prove the equivalence of both notions. Thank you for the help though.